# Validate data in a "Copy All" button from a ComboBox to a List

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to validate a "Copy All" button that can only copy, from a ComboBox, the data that is not already present on the List.

This is my code:

```
 String ele;      

    //if the List has 0 data, then it copies everything from the ComboBox        

    if(model.getSize()== 0){   
    for (int i = 0; i < cbxNum2.getItemCount(); i++) {
        ele = cbxNum2.getItemAt(i).toString(); 
        model.addElement(ele);        
    }

    //Trying to validate if the data is already on the List, so I can skip it.

    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < cbxNum2.getItemCount(); i++) {
            ele = cbxNum2.getItemAt(i).toString();
            for (int j = 0; j < model.getSize(); j++) {
                if(!model.getElementAt(i).equals(ele)){
                    model.addElement(ele);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

It works well when the List has 0 items, but when I add a new item to the ComboBox and try to copy it into the List I get this error:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
```

Comment: `model.getElementAt(i)` should be `model.getElementAt(j)`, but beware, under your current code, for each element that isn't equal to `ele` you are going to add `ele` to the `model`, which will increase the size of your model on each iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.getElementAt(i)` should be `model.getElementAt(j)`, but beware, under your current code, for each element that isn't equal to `ele` you are going to add `ele` to the `model`, which will increase the size of your model on each iteration

A better solution would be to check if `ele` is in the `model` and only if you don't find a match, add it, maybe something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < cbxNum2.getItemCount(); i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    ele = cbxNum2.getItemAt(i).toString();
    for (int j = 0; j < model.getSize(); j++) {
        if (model.getElementAt(j).equals(ele)) {
            found = true;
            break
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        model.addElement(ele);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! I knew I had to use a second for loop, just got confused how to set the boolean of found correctly. I've used those boolean but in cases of single for loops. Thanks for the code.